# Como solucionar: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$clave in inventariop\modelo\modeloLogin.php on line 41

Tags: php, mysql

Quisiera saber como solucionar el NOTICE de PHP el cual se muestra al momento de acceder al valor de un array devuelto por una consulta preparada, estoy usando PDO para realizar la conexión a MySQL

Sucede que me encuentro realizando la validación de un login donde la clave está encriptada para el cual usé `password_hash` y luego cuando deseo realizar la verificación con `password_verify` me sale el notice antes mencionado.

Asimismo quisiera aclarar que el código para validaUsuario funciona sin problemas con otros formularios, pero cuando lo intento hacer con MVC me muestra ese error.

**Código PHP del controladorLogin**

```
<?php
require_once '../modelo/modeloLogin.php';
require_once 'funciones.php';

$usuario=limpiaCadena($_POST['usuario']);
$clave=limpiaCadena($_POST['clave']);

$login = new modeloLogin();
$band=$login->validaUsuario($usuario,$clave);

if (!empty($usuario) && !empty($clave)) {
    if ($band) {
        //$_SESSION["usuario"] = $usuario;
        echo "Bienvenido!";
        echo "<script>window.location.replace('index.php');</script>";
    }else {
        echo "<span>Usuario y/o Contraseña incorrectos!</span>";
    }
}else{
    echo "<span>Por favor complete todos los campos!</span>";
}

?>
```

**Código PHP del modeloLogin**

```
<?php

class modeloLogin{
    private $conexion;

    public function modeloLogin(){
        require_once 'conexion_pdo.php';
        $this->conexion=conexion::conectar();
    }

public function validaUsuario($usuario,$clave){
    $query="SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE USUARIO=:usuario";
    $resulset=$this->conexion->prepare($query);
    $resulset->bindParam(':usuario',$usuario,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $resulset->execute();
    $array=$resulset->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    if (password_verify($clave,$array->clave)){//Esta es la línea que me marca el NOTICE
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

**Actualización 1**

Los campos de mi tabla en la BD estan todos en mayúsculas tal cual se muestra líneas abajo.

Esto es lo que devuelve el `var_dump($array)`

```
object(stdClass)#4 (7) { ["ID_USUARIO"]=> int(2) ["NOMBRE"]=> string(5) "Jorge" ["USUARIO"]=> string(13) "administrador" ["CLAVE"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$0vlzWykq7ZlnYse0nLktj.yr36sYZFeOvM59s0bgWRshmoiGt6Rqu" ["PERFIL"]=> string(13) "Administrador" ["IMAGEN"]=> string(4) "holi" ["ESTADO"]=> string(6) "Activo" }
```

Esto es lo que devuelve el `print_r($array)`

```
stdClass Object ( [ID_USUARIO] => 2 [NOMBRE] => Jorge [USUARIO] => administrador [CLAVE] => $2y$10$0vlzWykq7ZlnYse0nLktj.yr36sYZFeOvM59s0bgWRshmoiGt6Rqu [PERFIL] => Administrador [IMAGEN] => holi [ESTADO] => Activo )
```

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de que tu query no esta retornando valores o no tiene un campo llamado clave.

Comment: Ante este tipo de fallos, haz un `var_dump($array)` antes del if y mira que suelta

Comment: Mi tabla de la BD si tiene el campo clave y otros mas, ahora mi consulta si funciona, porque devuelve el array con los datos del usuario buscado. El problema esta en que no me deja acceder al valor del array que tiene el campo "clave"

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con @FranciscoGarrido, en estos casos lo primero que hay que hacer es **depurar**, para ver lo que hay en el objeto, por tanto, con un  **`var_dump($array);`**  vas a salir de toda duda, sabrás lo que hay en el dato y te habrás ahorrado horas quizá rompiéndote la cabeza tratando de encontrar el problema.

Comment: @A.Cedano He probado de todo para depurar use **`var_dump($array)`** imprimí el arreglo con **`print_r($array)`** todo va bien y en ambos casos de encontrar el usuario buscado me devuelve el array con todos sus datos y si no lo encuentra devuelve `false` el cual se controla en el `controladorLogin`

Comment: Pero nada de teoría, muestrános lo que imprime el `var_dump` en pantalla para verlo y analizar su constitución. Por ejemplo, me parece que los nombres de propiedades son *case sensitive*. O sea, que si la columna se llama `Clave`, no funcionará con `clave`... así que queremos ver el objeto por dentro para ver lo que hay realmente en él.

Comment: @A.Cedano Ya encontré la solución, tienes razón los nombres de la BD son *case sensitive* y no lo sabía solo tenía que poner el campo del dato al que quiero acceder en mayúsculas tal como se encuentra definida en la BD. Por otro lado indagando un poco encontré en la documentación de PHP que existe otra manera de acceder a los datos del array usando `next(), prev(), current()` así que probé y también funciona sin problemas. Ahora pregunta sería, que tan recomendado es usar las funciones que ofrece PHP.

Comment: ¿Para qué quieres usar `next(), prev(), current()` en este contexto?

Comment: No tengo ningún motivo en específico pero mientras buscaba una solución me encontré con ello y decidí probarlo. Por eso pregunté que tan recomendado era usarlo, pero no que fuera a implementarlo. De todas formas gracias por tu ayuda :D

Comment: En `$array` lo que tú tienes en realidad es un objeto, dado que has usado `fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` ... de hecho, deberías ser coherente en la convención de nombres, porque eso no es un array y creo que incluso te confunde o confunde a otros. Para acceder a los valores del objeto tan solo basta con usar la notación `$objeto->propiedad`, `next, prev, current` tienen otros usos. Incluso aquí si sólo esperas una fila, podrías poner `LIMIT 1` en la consulta.

Answer (score -3):

loque pasa es que tu query devuelve un array y tu por lo visto quieres acceder como un objeto en ese caso tienes que convertir tu array en un objeto.
Ej.:

```
$objeto = (object) $array;
print $objeto->clave;
```

ó

```
print $array["clave"];
```

Comment: No es correcto lo que dices, él está usando `$array=$resulset->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`, [si lees la doc sobre los *fetch_style*](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php)  comprenderás que cuando se usa `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` se devuelve un objeto, no un array.